# VLOOKUP Excel Funciton

Tags: excel

My apologies for such a basic question but it is indeed why it brings me here. For whatever reason, VLOOKUP isn't working for a set of data in a spreadsheet I have. Didn't really know where else to post but here...hoping someone could offer some insight on something I'm perhaps missing? I kid you not, I have the exact same setup on other spreadsheets with VLOOKUP and for whatever reason it's not working on this sheet. I've tried setting up multiple versions and even the online excel app

pls help

I keep getting that bloody #N/A[image]

Comment: Can you give us your formula?

Comment: =VLOOKUP($AA2,A:S,8,FALSE) in the screenshot as well

Comment: try: `=VLOOKUP($AA2,A$2:S$<foo>,8,FALSE)` where <foo> is the last row of your table.

Comment: Can't see images here - is the value in `AA2` a number or date?  Is the matching value in column `A` also formatted as a number?   If it's a date does one date have a time value and the other  doesn't, but both are formatted to appear the same?

Comment: If you're only look across to column 8 you could just use `A:H` rather than `A:S`.

Comment: none of that worked, any more ideas?

Comment: probably failing because there is no exact match. You haven't shown us the full spreadsheet so we can't tell. When in doubt, replace VLOOKUP() with INDEX() and MATCH() (which is faster and better anyway)

Comment: There's an exact match, I checked.

Comment: There's an issue with the text itself. I don't know how, but I tried a different column and it worked perfectly. Though it doesn't really solve my problem, it should provide us with a better direction if someone can figure out? My syntax is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can get the `#N/A` error if your `lookup_value` isn't "clean". If that's the case, try this formula:

`=VLOOKUP(TRIM(CLEAN($AA2)),A:S,8,FALSE)`

Additionally, your `table_array` may have "unclean" data, so you'll need to scrub that first before you're able to find a match. To do that, use this **array** formula, committing it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

`=VLOOKUP($AA2,TRIM(CLEAN(A:S)),8,FALSE)`

You may need to reduce your `table_array` area down from the entire columns of `A:S` in order to get the array formula to work. Otherwise, Excel may run out of resources.